# why I can't combine the two string together?

Tags: c, string

```
 char* key;

 key=(char*)malloc(100);

 memset(key,'\0',100*sizeof(char));
 char*  skey="844607587";

 char* mess="hello world";


 sprintf(key,skey);

 sprintf(key,mess);
 printf("%s",key);
 free(key);
```

why does the printout only have the "mess" don't have skey? is there any other way to combine two strings using C?

Comment: You overwriten the last value `sprintf(key,mess);`

Comment: Despite the spaghetti, it is possible (and sometimes necessary) to use `key+strlen(skey)` as destination for the second `sprintf`. Just note that I said you *could*, **not** _should_, it is **dangerous** if you don't know exactly what you're doing.

Comment: also better to use `snprintf`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sprintf(key,"%s%s",skey,mess);
```

for adding them separately :

```
sprintf(key,"%s",skey);
strcat(key, mess);
```

Comment: how about one by one, not combing at the same time

Comment: unfortunately not by sprintf .. because it will overwrite.

Comment: @SongZhibo because you over-writes the previous value with key's value

Comment: You can use strcat ,strcpy

Comment: @sukhvir add two step suggestion in answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `sprintf` twice on the same buffer, so it gets overwritten.

You could use `strcat` like this:

```
strcpy(key, skey);
strcat(key, mess);
```

Answer (score 1):

`sprintf(key,skey);`

It writes `skey` to `key`.

```
sprintf(key,mess);
```

It writes `mess` to `key`, overwriting previously written `skey`.

So you should use this:

```
sprintf(key,"%s%s", skey, mess);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
printf("Contcatened string = %s",strcat(skey,mess));
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to missing format string there were also some other problems:

```
char* key;
key = malloc(100); // Don't cast return value of malloc in C
// Always check if malloc fails
if(key) {
    memset(key, '\0' , 100 * sizeof(char));
    const char * skey = "844607587"; // Use const with constant strings
    const char * mess = "hello world";
    // sprintf requires format string like printf
    // Use snprintf instead of sprintf to prevent buffer overruns
    snprintf(key, 100, "%s%s", skey, mess); 
    printf("%s", key);
    free(key);
}
```

**Edit:**

Version with `calloc` would replace `malloc` and remove `memset`:

```
key = calloc(100, sizeof(char));
if(key) {
    const char * skey = "844607587";
```

Comment: @mvp True, better to use `calloc` if available.

Answer (score 0):

your code is follows

```
sprintf(key,skey);
sprintf(key,mess);
printf("%s",key);
```

result will be  "hello world"

you may change code to as follows

```
sprintf(key, "%s%s", skey, key);
printf("%s",key);
```

the result as follows "844607587hello world"

Answer (score 0):

the code is as below:

```
strncpy(key, skey, strlen(skey));
strcat(key, mess);
```